# jQuery UI Autocomplete Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to put an autocomplete input on my website and I have decided to just use the jQuery UI autocomplete widget since I ran into some problems.  But this doesn't solve everything!

Here's a link to an example I did: http://jsfiddle.net/Tg7Rt/2/

Here are my problems:

- The user needs to click on the actual word in the ui-menu box that drops down.  I want the user to be able to click on the same line, i.e. to the right of the word.
- Let's say the user wanted to put in the word 'Peach', which isn't found in the autocomplete.  I would want the user to press 'enter' and be able add the word to the .list

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first request, remember to include also jQuery ui css. For the second, add

```
$('#my_input').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13){
        $('ul').append("<li>" + this.value + "</li>");
        this.value = '';
    }


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tg7Rt/7/

Comment: for the 1st requst: just add css: `.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item a{
    display:block;
}`